# Can't install gem sqlite-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

After installing `sqlite`, `libsqlite0-dev` and `libsqlite3-dev` (and `ruby1.9.3` of course) on my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, I do :

```
sudo gem install sqlite-ruby
```

And here is the log I got :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lsqlite... yes
checking for sqlite.h... yes
checking for sqlite_open() in -lsqlite... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling sqlite-api.c
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_api_open':
sqlite-api.c:273:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_api_compile':
sqlite-api.c:335:28: warning: passing argument 2 of 'sqlite_compile' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/sqlite.h:657:5: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_api_complete':
sqlite-api.c:548:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'sqlite_complete' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/sqlite.h:260:5: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_api_set_result':
sqlite-api.c:783:24: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
sqlite-api.c:784:24: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_api_set_result_error':
sqlite-api.c:820:53: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'ptr'
sqlite-api.c:821:20: error: 'struct RString' has no member named 'len'
sqlite-api.c: In function 'static_raise_db_error':
sqlite-api.c:1181:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
make: *** [sqlite-api.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite-ruby-2.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite-ruby-2.2.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

Can somebody help me on installing that lib ? (my main problem is to migrate a [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) project to a [Redmine](http://redmine.org) [following that documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate))

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: What compiler do you mean ? I use all the defaults of Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS... for instance, GCC is 4.6.3, `ruby -v` gives `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Did you mean to install the `sqlite-ruby` gem?  There is a `sqlite3-ruby` gem which is more up-to-date.

Comment: Actually, it's [Redmine migration guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate) which tells me to install that specific lib, and not `sqlite3-ruby` because my Trac db is `sqlite` and not `sqlite3`, you think the `sqlite3-ruby` can also read `sqlite` dbs ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  The documentation for sqlite3-ruby explicitly states it is NOT compatible with sqlite before sqlite3.

Comment: The problem could well be your version of Ruby.  Have a look at this document - http://boga.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/ruby-19-porting-notes/  - point 8 is the same error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Graeme McLean's comment my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098627/cant-install-gem-sqlite-ruby#comment33520659_22098627), http://boga.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/ruby-19-porting-notes/, https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405578 and http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/, I managed to patch the `sqlite-ruby` gem, build it and install it :

```
gem fetch sqlite-ruby
gem unpack sqlite-ruby-2.2.3.gem
cd sqlite-ruby-2.2.3/
sed -i 's/RSTRING(\(.*\))->ptr/RSTRING_PTR(\1)/g' ext/sqlite-api.c
sed -i 's/RSTRING(\(.*\))->len/RSTRING_LEN(\1)/g' ext/sqlite-api.c
gem unpack --spec ../sqlite-ruby-2.2.3.gem
sed -i 's/version: 2.2.3/version: 2.2.3.patched/' sqlite-ruby-2.2.3.gemspec
cat >> sqlite-ruby-2.2.3.gemspec <<EOF

cert_chain: []
licenses: []
required_rubygems_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version::Requirement
  requirements:
    -
      - ">="
      - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
    version: 1.8.0
  version:
EOF
gem build sqlite-ruby-2.2.3.gemspec
sudo gem install sqlite-ruby --local
```